# Concatenate env variable value with string in command line

Tags: windows, shell, command-line

This is Windows 7 command prompt question.

Suppose I have environment variable which were set in a next way:

```
set FILE_SRC="D:\Users\me\Documents and Settings"
```

I would like to call form command line utility which will get one of directory files as argument:

```
fooUtil.exe %FILE_SRC%\fileName.txt
```

In this case shell fails to construct correct path string. Instead of it utility get next argument:

```
"D:\Users\me\Documents and Settings"\fileName.txt
```

What is a correct way? Again, I talk about prompt command line and not a batch file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just skip the quote marks when setting the variable. The variable will be set to the value terminated by a newline, not space.

Comment: Thank you, it works. I just have to add quotes at call fooUtil.exe "%FILE_SRC%\fileName.txt"

Comment: What's the right way to do this when working with environment variables that are set by Windows, like %DESKTOP% ?

Comment: @serilain, I am not sure what you mean? There is no difference between built-in variables and user-created variables, at least not when it comes to how they are handled in string concatenation - at least not as far as i know.

Answer (score 3):

I make it so ...

`set "FILE_SRC=D:\Users\me\Documents and Settings"
fooUtil.exe "%FILE_SRC%\fileName.txt"`

This works also with special characters.

`set "line=lines & edges = figures"
@echo "%line%"`

Comment: Thank you sir! I'm working on a batch file in my spare time that will mostly automate (hopefully) SQL scripts that contain a bunch of statements that must be manually executed now. I've prompted for user input and then am using that input in SQL statements.